# Rangers making attacks with different melee weapons?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, ranger

I'm somewhat confused by the Ranger class attack powers from the Player's Handbook. Many powers require the player to wield two melee weapons. What's bothering me is the damage: the book says the damage for Careful Attack is 1[W]. But what if you are using two different melee weapons? For example, if I'm holding a longsword in my main hand, whose damage is 1d8; and a short sword in my off hand, whose damage is 1d6, which do I use for damage? The attack suggests that you use both weapons for the attack, but the damage is only 1[W], so what do I do?

Comment: I bequeath unto you, the WOTC Optimization Discussion boards. Direct Link to their Ranger Build guide: http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/2533216

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Direct Math for your question and an explanation about Careful Attack.**

Attack: Roll 1d20+to-hit modifier. If you hit roll (1d8 *OR* 1d6) + damage modifier .

Careful Attack's requirement to have two melee weapons or a ranged weapon is simply that, a requirement. When you make the attack while wielding two melee weapons you can choose which melee weapon you use (since it doesn't specify main-hand or off-hand). Unless your off hand shortsword had a better magical property you would always want to go with the bigger damage die of the mainhand weapon.

**Attacks that let you Attack more than once will specify whether or not you simply use the main-hand weapon or you do one for each hand**

> Twin Strike
>
> At-Will        Martial, Weapon
>   Standard Action      Melee or Ranged weapon
>
> Requirement: You must be wielding two melee weapons or a ranged weapon.
>
> Targets: One or two creatures
>
> Attack: Strength vs. AC (melee; main weapon and off-hand weapon) or Dexterity vs. AC (ranged), two attacks
>
> Hit: 1[W] damage per attack.

For example, twin strike specifies that when made as a melee attack it triggers on the main hand and then the off-hand weapons, thus you make 1 attack & damage roll for the main hand and a separate attack and damage roll using your off hand weapon (ranged rangers using Twin Strike simply roll twice for their ranged weapon).

**If you're playing a Two-Weapon ranger you should have chosen the Class Feature *Two-Blade Fighting Style***

> Two-Blade Fighting Style
>   Because of your focus on two-weapon melee attacks, you can wield a one-handed weapon in your off hand as if it were an off-hand weapon. (Make sure to designate on your character sheet which weapon is main and which is off-hand.) In addition, you gain Toughness as a bonus feat.

This is critical for Two-Weapon rangers because it allows you to have one handed weapons in both hands (without the off-hand property being required). Thus you should instead be using two identical longswords (or better yet if you have a feat to spend, pick up Weapon Proficiency:Bastard Sword. 1d10 high crit one handed weapon).